# How to customize a slider in kivy

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I would like to change the apereance of the kivy slider. So far I haven't found any properites to change the scrollbar and the circle. I think they are created by the use of canvas operations.

My vision is to extend the slider by displaying the current value below the circle which can be moved.

Any ideas?

Some code:

```
class templPowerSlider():
    kivy.lang.Builder.load_string('''
<templPowerSlider@BoxLayout>:
    sp: sp
    sl: sl
    val: val

    Spinner:
        id: sp
        values: ['mW', '%']
        text: '%'
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        on_text: root.onSel(*args)

    Slider:
        id: sl
        size_hint_x: 0.7

    TextInput:
        id: val
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        text: "%3.1f" % sl.value
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.onTextEnter(*args)
''')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(templPowerSlider, self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        pass

    def onSel(self, a, b):
        print ('aaa')

    def onTextEnter(self, a, b):
        print ('bb')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the UI of the `Slider` is created in canvas, and there are no properties to modify the display. If you like, you can change the way the `Slider` is displayed by overriding the kv design:

```
<-MySlider@Slider>:
    ....
```

The `-` tells Kivy to ignore previous rules and build this `MySlider` widget from scratch. You can copy the old rule from `style.kv` if you want to just make minor modifications to the display.

However, you don't necessarily need to modify the existing UI if you want to add a value text. Here is a simple example I came up with:

```
<MySlide@Slider>:
    Label:
        pos: (root.value_pos[0] - sp(16), root.center_y - sp(27)) if root.orientation == 'horizontal' else (root.center_x - sp(27), root.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
        size_hint: None, None
        size: sp(32), sp(32)
        text: str(root.value)
```

This just adds a `Label` below the `Slider` handle.

Comment: Yeah! - cool and simple solution. Never thought it is so easy.
Maybee you can help and give me a tip how to mix the template in the kv file and the code written in python. The (bad) example given at the question, does not work - because the root is the BoxLayout and the functions which should be called are in the inherritated class templPowerSlider. Any good solution for that problem?

Comment: You're mixing Python class widgets and dynamic class widgets. You have to pick one or the other. In this case, you should use `class TemplPowerSlider(BoxLayout):` and `<TemplPowerSlider>:`. Note that you should **always** capitalize the first letter of a widget class.